# ruby multithread, shared array

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I have the following code, where @targets is a hash with hostnames and ips, eg:

```
@targets = {
  "www.test.com"  => 1.2.3.4,
  "www.test2.com" => 4.3.2.1,
  "www.test2.com" => 23.24.25.23
}
```

There are three distinct "blocks" of code (block 1,2,3).
At the moment, every thread works on one host/ip pair.
I want to create three threads, one for each block.
So when block1 writes at `@targets["www.test.com"]` block2 waits.
When block1 finishes, block2 writes at `@targets["www.test.com"]`, but block1 doesn't wait. Instead it starts writing at `@targets["www.test2.com"]`.

This is something like mutex, but when i use mutex, i can't/don't know how to tell block1 "grab the next target"

```
require 'thread'

@targets = {
  "www.test.com"  => "1.2.3.4",
  "www.test1.com" => "4.3.2.1",
  "www.test2.com" => "23.24.25.23"
}

@vhosts={
"www.test.com"=>"web.test.com",
"www.test1.com"=>"Error",
"www.test2.com"=>"dev.test2.com"
}

@enumeration_summary={}

@targets.each do |host,ip|

  @initialize = Thread.new do

    #---------block1---------
    puts "Host: #{host} Ip: #{ip}"
    @enumeration_summary["#{host}"]={}
    #---------block1 end---------

    #---------block2---------
    @enumeration_summary["#{host}"]={ip: ip}
    #---------block2 end---------

    #---------block3---------
    if /Error/ === @vhosts["#{host}"]
       @enumeration_summary["#{host}"][:vhosts_number_of_results]=@vhosts["#{host}"]
    else
       @enumeration_summary["#{host}"][:vhosts_number_of_results]=@vhosts["#{host}"].size
    end
    #---------block3 end---------

  end #end thread

end #end of targets.each

 @initialize.join

puts "===> #{@enumeration_summary}"
```

Also sometimes i don't get all the results and i don't see why.
At this time, every thread accesses a different index of the @enumeration_summary hash. So why i don't get all the results all the time?
Example output:
Example 1. Everything ok:

```
Host: www.test.com Ip: 1.2.3.4
Host: www.test2.com Ip: 23.24.25.23Host: www.test1.com Ip: 4.3.2.1

===> {"www.test.com"=>{:ip=>"1.2.3.4", :vhosts_number_of_results=>12},  "www.test1.com"=>{:ip=>"4.3.2.1", :vhosts_number_of_results=>"Error"}, "www.test2.com"=>{:ip=>"23.24.25.23", :vhosts_number_of_results=>13}}
```

Example 2. Target test1.com is missing

```
Host: www.test.com Ip: 1.2.3.4
Host: www.test2.com Ip: 23.24.25.23
Host: www.test1.com Ip: 4.3.2.1
===> {"www.test.com"=>{:ip=>"1.2.3.4", :vhosts_number_of_results=>12}, "www.test2.com"=>{:ip=>"23.24.25.23", :vhosts_number_of_results=>13}}
```

P.S: i would like to work with "thread" only. I want to avoid using any other gem, like "parallel".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can work with [Queue](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html)

Comment: It would be much easier if I could just copy / paste / run your code. Can you post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: Sorry about that Stefan. I edited the post with a working code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested, but it relies on the example in the documentation for [Queue](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html). It passes a message from block1 to block2, and from block2 to block3, each handling messages as they arrive:

```
require 'thread'

queue = Queue.new
queue2 = Queue.new

producer = Thread.new do
  @targets.each do |host,ip|
    puts "Host: #{host} Ip: #{ip}"
    @enumeration_summary["#{host}"]={}
    queue << [host, ip, @enumeration_summary["#{host}"]]
  end
  queue = nil
end

consumer1 = Thread.new do
  while value = queue.pop
    value[2] = { ip: value[1] }
    queue2 << value
  end
  queue2 << nil
end

consumer2 = Thread.new do
  while value = queue2.pop
    if /Error/ === @vhosts[value[0]]
      value[2][:vhosts_number_of_results]=@vhosts[value[0]]
    else
      value[2][:vhosts_number_of_results]=@vhosts[value[0]].size
    end
  end
end

consumer2.join
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating your threads, you assign each thread to `@initialize`: (overwriting the variable's previous value)

```
@targets.each do |host, ip|
  @initialize = Thread.new do
    # ...
  end
end
@initialize.join
```

The last line then only waits for the thread assigned to `@initialize`, i.e. the last thread.

In order to wait for all threads, you have to assign them to an array, e.g.:

```
@threads = []
@targets.each do |host, ip|
  @threads << Thread.new do
    # ...
  end
end
@threads.each(&:join)
```